# 2.1 Bass Configurations for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: sound, logitech

I bought logitech S220 2.1.

The system includes a subwoofer. It works on Windows OS but i can't get the same quality on Linux 12.04.

As i see, there are 5 options (2, 4.1, 4, 5.1, 5) but i think it requires 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use 2 (or 2.0)**

Your S-220 system ([see datasheet, page 2](http://www.businessdirect.bt.com/content/uni2/documentation/4l6m/4l6m_data_sheet.pdf)) has a standard stereo two-channel/2.0 3.5 mm input, and bass adjustments are done via a knob at the back of the subwoofer, NOT from software.

This is unlike higher-end 5.1 systems which have a separate audio input for the subwoofer.